# Create a program that listen a message from socket connection in python

Tags: python

I want to create a program that listen message from client in socket connection ,but I stuck at socket.accept() because when it wait for incoming message. It can't do the next line of code so my processing is block by socket.accept(). I read about non-blocking socket, but I still confuse about how it work. Did you have any idea to solve this problem ?

**The program I want look like this**

if(not receives new message) -> do another process

else -> receives the message until close connection

server.py

```
import socket
 
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5432

cameras = list()
 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen()

def process():
  print("x")

while True: 
  connection, client_address = s.accept()
  process()
  try:
    print("Socket is now conneted")
    print(client_address)
    while True:
      data = connection.recv(1024)

      if data:
          print("received:", data.decode("utf-8"))
          connection.sendall(b'ok')
      else:
          break
  
  finally:
      connection.close()
      print("closed connection")
```

client.py

```
from tcpClient import SocketClient

socket = SocketClient()

socket.connet()

while True:
    x = input()
    socket.send(x)
    if x == "q":
        socket.close()
        break;
```

Comment: Please include the code you have written so far.

Comment: If all your application is supposed to do is to listen - then why would you need to go any further until something actually comes?

Comment: @PM77-1 The reasons is I create a programs that can config my camera with OpenCV such as addCam, removeCam, setIp, start, stop so I think if I create socket server to listen message from client while capture the video from a camera it will work or Did you have suggestion ?

Comment: You are supposed to start listening only after you are completely ready to process the response.